# java.net.ConnectException/java.net.ConnectException depending on normal run or debug mode

Tags: java, sockets, connection, outputstream, tcp

Hi am trying to send a binary message to a server with the IP and Port:

192.168.2.101:10001

The socket is reopened every 50 messages.

If I run the application normally I get a java.net.ConnectException in line 5, even though I can ping and telnet the server.

If I debug the application I get a java.net.SocketException at a different line (11), also sometimes the first message seems to get through without any errors.

```
private void sendMessage(String message, int relaisId, long timestamp) {

    try {
        if (connCount > 50) {
            s = new Socket(ip, port); //RUN NORMALLY: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
            connCount=0;
        }
        outputStream = s.getOutputStream();

        outputStream.write(message.getBytes());
        outputStream.write(new byte[]{0});//DEBUG: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        outputStream.flush();
        connCount++;
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        logger.error("Host not found: " + ip + ":" + port, ex);
        connCount=51;
        retryMessage(message, relaisId, timestamp);// basically sleep 3s then call sendMessage
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error("Error at Relais No. " + relaisId + ": " + ip + ":" + port, ex);
        connCount=51;
        retryMessage(message, relaisId, timestamp); // basically sleep 3s then call sendMessage
    } finally {
        try {
            if (connCount > 50 && s != null) {
                s.close();                    
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error("IOException", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or analysis tools are very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In my program different Threads send messages to external hardware components over given IPs and Ports. 
This error occured because a Thread accidently got initiated twice with the same IP address and port, resulting in timing conflicts while using the same socket.

Even more strange was, that this error started to occur permanently while changing the server machine, before it was only there sporadically and we thought it was a noise in the network communication.

Hope this is a help to anyone in the future :)